# Find the MAC address of all devices connected to the same Wifi network

Tags: java, ping, router, mac-address, arp

I'm trying to build a software that checks what devices are connected to my home network and return a list of those device's MAC address every 10 minutes or so.

My approach was to ping all of the possible IP addresses on the network and call "arp -a" afterwards.

The following code works to find if a device is registered on an IP address, but I don't know how to get the MAC address from this.

```
try {
            String currentIP = InetAddress.getLocalHost().toString();
            String subnet = getSubnet(currentIP);
            System.out.println("subnet: " + subnet);

            for (int i=1;i<254;i++){

                String host = subnet + i;
                System.out.println("Checking :" + host);

                if (InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeout)){
                    System.out.println(host + " is reachable");
                    try {
                        Socket connected = new Socket(subnet, port);
                    }
                    catch (Exception s) {
                        System.out.println(s);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You're blindly assuming IPV4, which is not so reasonable anymore these days.

And you're trying to dig out information that routers and access points *have no good reason for disclosing* in the first place (at least not to robots who won't authenticate themselves as an admin with access rights to the router's or access point's admin page).

Answer (score 0):

Try this [one](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-mac-address-in-java/).

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class App{

   public static void main(String[] args){

    InetAddress ip;
    try {

        ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        System.out.println("Current IP address : " + ip.getHostAddress());

        NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);

        byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();

        System.out.print("Current MAC address : ");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));        
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (SocketException e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

   }

}
```

This `NetworkInterfaceNetworkInterface.getHardwareAddress()` method is only allowed to access localhost MAC address, not remote host MAC address.

**Note : You can't do this in remotely for PC or Device in java.But you can do it by using C# and WMI - [WMI with netowrk in .NET language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394595%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

Comment: -1 This is NOT a solution to the problem "I'm trying to build a software that checks what devices are connected to my home network and return a list of those device's MAC address".